# Missing iPhone simulator from Interface Builder in Xcode 13

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, ios-simulator

In Xcode 13, I added an iPhone 7 Plus simulator that appears to work. However, when I open one of my XIB files, the iPhone 7 size is missing from the Interface Builder list. I already restarted Xcode to no avail. How can I add the iPhone 7 Plus in this list?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are designing an interface here. Those are merely *screen sizes*. The iPhone 8 screen is identical to the iPhone 7 screen, and the iPhone SE 2 is the same as both (375x667, 2x), so no point listing more than the iPhone SE 2.

Comment: Good list here: https://www.ios-resolution.com

Comment: Thanks @matt. I was checking https://www.ios-resolution.com/ and noticed the iPhone 7 Plus (not iPhone 7 - I edited my question, sorry!) logical width and height (476 x 847) is not available in my list of screen sizes - the only other simulators that match the screen size are the iPhone 6s Plus and iPhone 6 Plus - which I don't have either.

Comment: Well, the 7 plus is a weird one because it has a bizarre scaling factor. The 8 plus is actually the same effective size. That chart fails to capture that fact; maybe we need to look for a better chart.